# How to get data from model with parameter in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, argument-passing

hello everyone i have a question about get data from model with parameter, i can't call data in view

this is my model

```
    function nilai_mahasiswa($ni_dos,$kd_smt,$kd_kls){
    $data_nilai_mahasiswa = $this->db->query("SELECT dat_jadwal_kuliah.ni_dos, dat_dosen.nama_dos, tab_mata_kuliah.nama_mt_klh, dat_krs.nim_mhs, dat_mahasiswa.nama_mhs, ".
        " dat_krs.kd_mt_klh, dat_krs.kd_kls, dat_krs.jml_hadir, dat_krs.nilai_tugas, dat_krs.nilai_uts, dat_krs.nilai_uas, dat_krs.nilai_akhir, ".
        " dat_krs.grade ".
        " FROM dat_jadwal_kuliah ".
        " INNER JOIN dat_krs ON (dat_jadwal_kuliah.kd_mt_klh = dat_krs.kd_mt_klh AND dat_jadwal_kuliah.kd_pst = dat_krs.kd_pst AND dat_jadwal_kuliah.kd_kls=dat_krs.kd_kls) ".
        " INNER JOIN dat_dosen ON dat_jadwal_kuliah.ni_dos = dat_dosen.ni_dos ".
        " INNER JOIN dat_mahasiswa ON dat_krs.nim_mhs = dat_mahasiswa.nim_mhs ".
        " INNER JOIN tab_mata_kuliah ON dat_krs.kd_mt_klh = tab_mata_kuliah.kd_mt_klh ".
        " WHERE dat_jadwal_kuliah.ni_dos='".$ni_dos."' AND dat_krs.kd_smt='".$kd_smt."' AND dat_krs.kd_kls='".$kd_kls."' ".
        " ORDER BY dat_krs.nim_mhs asc");
    return $data_nilai_mahasiswa;       
}
```

this is my controller

```
function inputnilai($ni_dos,$kd_smt,$kodemata,$kd_kls) {
    if($this->session->userdata('isLogin') == FALSE)
    {
        redirect('login/login_form');
    }else
    {
        $data['semester'] = "$kd_smt";
        $data['kelas'] = "$kd_kls";
        $data['kodemata'] = "$kodemata";
        $data['nidos'] = "$ni_dos";
        $this->load->model('m_jadwal','',TRUE);
        $user = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $data['pengguna'] = $this->m_login->dataPengguna($user);
        $data['kdsmtaktif'] = $this->m_login->smtaktif();
        $data['data_nilai_mahasiswa'] = $this->m_jadwal->nilai_mahasiswa($ni_dos,$kd_kls,$kd_smt);
        $this->load->view('aka_v',$data);
        $this->load->view('inputnilai_v',$data);
    }
}
```

at last this is my view

```
            <?php
            foreach($data_nilai_mahasiswa as $row)
            {
                echo $row['nim_mhs'];
                echo $row['nama_mhs'];
                echo "<br>";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: only this variable is not showing or other variables also don't have data..?

Comment: how can i show variable from other form and send variable into model

Comment: my mean is `$nidos` is echoing something?

Comment: yes, nidos is call variable from the other form

Comment: does it print something in html.?

Comment: yes it print something, like call name and id from $nidos

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your view section `$data_nilai_mahasiswa` is an array and you are fetching its element as `$row` but still you are using `$row` as array `$row['nim_mhs']` thats wrong.

You can use

```
        <?php
            foreach($data_nilai_mahasiswa as $row)
            {
                echo $row;

                echo "<br>";
            }
      // or 
           echo $data_nilai_mahasiswa['nim_mhs'];
            ?>
```

Comment: still error , this error i have after insert that "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Than i think there is a problem with your sql query.

Comment: no, my sql it's right and i tested it's working navicat mysql